# How to add the Symfony Profiler to a Symfony 4.4 project?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to add the profiler to a Symfony 4.4 project. Using `symfony/profiler-pack` adds the latest version, so version 5 and newer. It did not work. After some googling I found that I have to add `Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['all' => true]` to `config/bundles.php`. (Yes, I know not to leave *all* there.)
So instead I explicitely used the version we use:

```
"symfony/stopwatch": "4.4.4",
"symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.4",
"symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "4.4.4"
```

When I load the page I get the following error message in my browser:

> Symfony \ Component \ DependencyInjection \ Exception \ 
>   ServiceNotFoundException
>   The service "web_profiler.controller.profiler" has a dependency on a non-existent service "twig".

You can find the code and my change here: https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/foodsharing/-/commit/fe6e6ebb3c2356e56a3d7f5757f0dcaf6d1a1557

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The Profiler bundles requires Twig, did you configure the twig bundle and is the service there? `php bin/console debug:container twig`

Comment: I was not aware that there needs to be configured anything. You command results in `no config found for env []` so I guess no. https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html#installation only gives the installation command. What do I need to do?

Comment: if that command returns no results, you do not have the twig bundle activated I guess? Is the TwigBundle loaded in your bundles.php?

Comment: Consider creating a new Symfony website-skeleton which includes the profiler and using it as a comparison.

Comment: @Jeroen it seems so. I thought this happens automatically. But this project is a bit older and some other people have updated it before. Perhaps there are things missing. I'll check that.

Comment: @Cerad good idea. I actually found some differences. https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/foodsharing/-/blob/master/config/packages/services.yml#L15 Twig is configured in some way, but it is not even loaded via the bundles.php. I think I have to fix that. Though I am not quite sure what the twig config in services.yml does.